# How to tell if the city is incorrect in Android openweatherMap API?

Tags: android, weather-api, android-xmlpullparser, openweathermap

I'm using **XmlPullParser** to parse the weather information from the API. My application shows the weather information once the user entered his city (input). If I enter enter "London" in the text box, my app goes to [this](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml&units=metric) and fetches the temperature, humidity etc. from the xml (at this point everything works as expected). But when I enter "Londonsd" my app hangs up.

Message I'm getting from the server when I enter incorrect city is "{"message":"Error: Not found city","cod":"404"}".

Comment: simply parse the response from the server and apply conditions to give message to user. In above case, if you are getting above message, check value pair for the key "message". If the value happens to be "Error"Not found city", use TextView or something in your layout to show no city found.

Comment: Thanks @Sujit I used the same idea as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting two types of data responses in case of success get xml and in case of failure getting json make them identical first. I will suggest use json by changing `mode=json` http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=json&units=metric.

After that you can put a check on `cod` if there is 404 then city is invalid.

or

You can try `response.contains("\"cod\":\"404\"");` or `response.contains("Not found city");` for checking error. but not ideal solution.

Comment: thank you for your response @Ahmad Nawaz. I don't want to change it to json, because I have to rewrite the code again.

Comment: Then you can try `response.contains("\"cod\":\"404\"");` or `response.contains("Not found city");` for checking error. but not ideal solution.